# service run in thread in Grails 3.3.0

Tags: java, multithreading, grails

I user Grails 3.3.0 with Java8. Below is my controller:

```
class TtController {

    def index() {
        List<SignRecord>signRecordList = SignRecord.executeQuery(
                "From SignRecord where convert(Date,signDate) = '2020-01-07' "
        )
        int count = -1
        while (count < 10) {
            count++
            log.info("${count}")
            Thread.start {
                def processService
                processService.process(signRecordList[count])
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It happened below error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-22" Exception in thread "Thread-26" Exception in thread "Thread-27" Exception in thread "Thread-23" Exception in thread "Thread-25" Exception in thread "Thread-24" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method process() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.fet.beaconweb.test.TtController$_index_closure1$$ERn3X8X3.doCall(TtController.groovy:18)
    at com.fet.beaconweb.test.TtController$_index_closure1$$DRn3X8X3.doCall(Unknown Source)
```

So, how to let a service run in a thread ?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like `signRecordList` object is `null `.

Comment: no. the processService in Thread.start {} is null